# NLog format memory in MB

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to log my memory consumption every time i do a logging. It works, but the issue is the data presented is in bytes. How can i do some maths to convert it to MB. I tried with /1024 but it gives error.

I want to format ${gc:property=TotalMemory}B

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="MEM_LOG" fileName="${basedir}/SystemLog/${var:SystemId}_MEM_LOG_${var:KioskId}_${shortdate}.txt"
        encoding="utf-8"               
      layout="${longdate}|${assembly-version:type=Assembly:format=major.minor.build.revision}|${var:KioskId}|${uppercase:${level}}|${threadid}|${callsite}|${callsite-linenumber}|${gc:property=TotalMemory}B" />
```

Comment: Maybe create a custom layout renderer? I have never tried, but it should allow you to write some code to convert the number however you want. My preference is to have a bit of code that automatically selects SI prefix depending on the size, and includes two or three significant digits when converting to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [custom layout-renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer) in your application like this:

```
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(ext => ext.RegisterLayoutRenderer("GcMegaBytes", (l) => "42")));
```

And then you can output in whatever format you like.